Library gradle build issue - com.siimkinks.sqlitemagic:sqlitemagic-plugin:0.23.1
Lately, we've been facing difficulties with the sqlitemagic library in our project. A few days ago, I came across a builder issue and attempted to resolve it by updating mavenCentral() in the gradle file, but the problem persisted. I also tried adding the sqlitemagic (.jar) files, but it didn't work. I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found one yet.
Could you please share the solution for this issue.!
enter image description here
Bild Gradle issue:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.siimkinks.sqlitemagic:sqlitemagic-plugin:0.23.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/siimkinks/sqlitemagic/sqlitemagic-plugin/0.23.1/sqlitemagic-plugin-0.23.1.pom
         https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/siimkinks/sqlitemagic/sqlitemagic-plugin/0.23.1/sqlitemagic-plugin-0.23.1.jar
         https://maven.google.com/com/siimkinks/sqlitemagic/sqlitemagic-plugin/0.23.1/sqlitemagic-plugin-0.23.1.pom
         


I've already attempted numerous methods, but to no avail. It would be better if you moved with room Db.
